# flag matching pos/neg pairs in a table with duplicates

Tags: sql, ms-access

Any advice on how I can delete or flag corresponding pairs of rows from a table that has duplicate rows? (Yes, it’s ugly; that’s the data I’m given.)

Consider a services-charge table: `< customer #, date, item #, quantity, charge >`

My data has these unfortunate features:

- No unique id. Duplicate rows. (Two identical charges on the same day result in two identical rows. We care about count() in addition to sum(), so two quantity-one rows are not the same as one row of quantity-two.)
- If a charge is cancelled, the original row is left *unchanged*; a similar row gets appended, with *negative quantity and charge*.

For example, we could have the following rows, reflecting a service performed twice in a day for the same customer, and where the original entries were backed out and re-entered. (Perhaps there was a problem in fields we don’t see.)

```
43, 3/1/2022, 17, 1, $5
43, 3/1/2022, 17, 1, $5     two charges
43, 3/1/2022, 17, -1, -$5
43, 3/1/2022, 17, -1, -$5   both charges reversed
43, 3/1/2022, 17, 1, $5
43, 3/1/2022, 17, 1, $5     both charges entered again
```

Like I said, the data is ugly! I want to delete (or flag) the positive-negative pairs. (In the above sample, delete the first 4 rows. Or the last 4, since they’re interchangeable.)

I’ve implemented this in Excel VBA, but would much rather have a non-VBA SQL solution.

Is this do-able? (It's easy to compute a list of all the distinct matching pairs. Adding an ID field to the table, probably one could delete a single positive/negative pair for each entry in that list. But even so, you'd need to run the query twice for the above example, where two pairs match the same entry. And I'm not even clear how to get that far.)

We’re running Microsoft Access in Office 365.

Comment: It will not be nice, neither neat, in SQL. Stick with VBA and your working solution.

Comment: Thanks, Gustav; maybe I will need to stick with VBA. SQL would have been nice for maintainability by future folks. Unless a solution is found here, I'll dig into Access VBA, to at least avoid the Excel step.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can just send the valid data to another table (copy the structure of the old one –adding a PK would be a good idea). Something like

```
Insert into new_table

Select customer, date, item, sum(quantity) as q, sum(charge) as c

From old_table
```

Comment: Pontnou, we need to preserve count() as well as sum(). But maybe regeneration is the key; if we compute a list of the distinct rows, with the number of times each should appear...

Comment: Thinking about regeneration:  let's simplify the example data to a single, integer field `< F1 >`. Order's unspecified; duplicates are meaningful; each <0 row cancels out one >0 row.
This could be represented cleanly as `< F1, n>` where F1 is positive, and n is the net # of occurrences. We can compute this from the ugly data. That leaves one puzzle: how to generate n rows of F1  for each  <F1,n>, thus re-creating the original data format, cleaned up.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, Mugwort. I’ve thought again about your problem, and I propose you an alternative solution. An auxiliary table is needed. This table has to be filled with integers from 1 to as many rows you require in your real data.

```
CREATE TABLE rows(n int NULL)  ON [PRIMARY]
insert into rows values(1)
insert into rows values(2)
insert into rows values(3)
insert into rows values(4)
insert into rows values(5)
insert into rows values(6)
insert into rows values(7)
insert into rows values(8)
insert into rows values(9)
insert into rows values(10)
```

I’ve created a [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3d9f06833e30e14ce4b94addf636aacb) post with a full example. There are some extra data just to validate the solution. Sample is in SQL Server, but it works as well in ms-access as long as the table and field names are the same (in ms-access you have to create a query).

```
SELECT q.customer, q.Date, q.item, [SumOfquantity]/q.n AS quantity, [SumOfcharge]/q.n AS charge
FROM 
    (SELECT data.customer, data.date, data.item, Sum(data.quantity) AS SumOfquantity, Sum(data.charge) AS SumOfcharge, Sum(IIf([quantity]<0,-1,1)) AS [n]
    FROM data
    GROUP BY data.customer, data.date, data.item)  AS q
    ,[rows]
WHERE rows.n <= q.n
ORDER BY q.customer, q.Date, q.item;
```

The solution is a bit tricky, but I think it should work with your data.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to clarifications from Pontnou, I arrived at a solution.
Notice that because the affected records are duplicates (or negatives of each other), we don’t need to preserve their individuality; we can re-generate the correct number of each.

To simplify the example, our data is in table Orders with fields <cust#, item#, quantity, cost>, where negative quantity and cost indicates a void which should erase one corresponding positive order. For now, we assume there are no unmatched voids, and no weird cases where only one of quantity and cost are negative.

Build a table called Samples, with the same fields as Orders.
Load it with distinct rows <cust#, item#, abs(quantity), abs(cost)>, where quantity<0. This identifies all the void cases. (There could be multiple matching pairs for each of these, if an order was entered and voided repeatedly.)

Build another table called Counts, with the same fields plus integer N.
To load it, left join Samples to Orders on cust# and item#, where Samples.quantity = abs(Orders.quantity) and Samples.cost = abs(Orders.cost), computing N as Sum( IIF(Orders.quantity>0, 1, -1) ), grouped by cust#, item#, Samples.cost, Samples.quantity. This computes how many rows should remain after voids are handled.

The tricky thing I was trying to do was to somehow retain exactly N matching records. There’s an easier way.
Delete all rows is Orders that match Counts in cust#, item#, abs(quantity), and abs(cost).
Now insert rows into Orders from Counts, where N>0, and where each row is replicated N times.
To do the latter: I happen to have a table T with many rows numbered consecutively from 1. Select from Counts and T, where T.number <= Counts.N, and you get the correct number of copies of each row of Counts.

This doesn't handle the error cases where a void doesn’t have a matching order to erase, quantity=0, or quantity>0 and cost<0.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32633323)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).